# Django override manager in admin

Tags: django, model, django-admin

I have a model which use a custom manager:

```
class ProjectManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ProjectManager, self).get_queryset() \
            .exclude(archived_date__isnull=False)


class Project(models.Model):
    objects = ProjectManager()
    archived_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

But I haven't found a way to display all Projects in the admin.

My admin is defined as follow:

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Project
```

I tried to use the `get_queryset` in the `ProjectAdmin` class, but I could not figure out a way to get back all projects.

Do you know a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to set the manager as default manager.

```
objects = ProjectManager() # The default manager.
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset

EDIT:

This might not be the best solution, but this will work.

models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    objects_unfiltered = models.Manager()
```

admin.py

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Project

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.objects_unfiltered.all()

admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```